# How to use <fmt:formatNumber> logic in own tag?

Tags: jsp, tags, jstl, el

Because I need to write out my objects in many templates in my app, I created own EL tag. Now I need to format numbers for myself. Is there a way how to use in this tag library class  possibilities that provides `formatNumber` tag in JSP template? Does `formatNumber` tag uses some external library which I can use?

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" value="${orders.getStatistics().getMin()}"  maxFractionDigits="1" />
```

I need only two format types (number and percent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just using the standard Java SE API provided [`java.text.NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) under the covers.

The tag's job can be represented in plain Java as follows, leaving locale outside consideration as you didn't specify it in your tag example (even though that would be pretty important to consider):

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
String result = formatter.format(number);
```